# Using XJC to compile a XSD with mutiple schema

Tags: xsd, xjc

I have a XSD of the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>

    <xs:schema --->
      ..
      ..
      </xs:schema>

       <xs:schema -->
      ..
      ..
      </xs:schema -->

       <xs:schema -->
      ..
      ..
      </xs:schema -->


</root>
```

It gives an error when compiled using XJC compiler at line 1 "Content is not allowed in prolog".
If I change the encoding to , "ISO-8859-1"

it gives followwing error:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected <root> appears at line 2 column 10
  line 2 of ****.xsd Failed to parse a schema.
```

If I remove the "root" tag, from the XSD, it starts giving the following error:

```
  [ERROR] The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
  line 44 of file:****.xsd
```

Failed to parse a schema.

My question is whether we can use XJC to compile a XSD with more than 1 schema tag. I had tried this with following file format :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="cdf">
      /xs:element>

    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

it worked perfectly well for the above , creating classes appropriately.

Does it has something to do with the namespace declaration?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the XSD spec allows multiple xs:schema elements to be included in the same XML document, so what you are trying to do is not unreasonable.  In practice, a lot of XSD software (perhaps most XSD software) is not prepared for schema documents in which the xs:schema element is not the outermost element in the XML document, and even when software does support other cases, different programs don't always agree on how to behave.

See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514361/is-it-possible-to-flatten-an-xml-schema-package-in-only-one-xsd-file) for further discussion, including a passionate argument from a misinformed party that there is no XSD software at all that supports input of the kind you describe.

With XJC, your best option appears to be to put each xs:schema element in a separate XML document and use (a) a single driver file to import or include each of them in turn, or (b) to put them all in the same directory and hand XJC the name of the directory; it will scan the directory for schema files and compile them.  You may also be able to do something with the `-wsdl` option.